# solr query analyzers

Tags: lucene, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am trying to use double metaphone as one of the analyzers for duplicate detection. here is how my schema looks like

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase=" true"words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And this works great for duplicate detection, but for some reason it screws up my original search result quality specially for non english words. Is there are way I can have search with and without using the double metaphone filter on my query string.

Thanks